# WebAPI OData DateTime error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Same question was asked here http://forums.asp.net/post/5243863.aspx but no answers yet.

A filter query like $filter=TimeRequested eq datetime'2012-12-17' OR $filter=TimeRequested eq datetime'2012-12-17T08:36:06' is erroring out with

Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.DateTime' for operator kind 'Equal'.

Comment: Are you sure TimeRequested isn't a string property in your model? I tried with this URL: "http://localhost/Customers?$filter=TimeRequested eq datetime'2012-12-20'" and it worked just fine in my case.

Comment: TimeRequested is a DateTime. I have tried with string as well without success. Can you let me know the version of Microsoft.Data.OData and Microsoft.Data.Edm? I am using the latest 5.2.0.0 version.

Comment: I´ve tested an it works ok. The filter is ok, the problem has to be in other place.

Comment: Can you get a callstack of the exception - that should help to narrow it down.

Comment: This problem went away after I upgraded to 5.2.0-rc1. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/721

Comment: I am using Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll (Runtime Version: v4.0.30319 Version: 6.3.0.0), and met the same datetime Edm.String issue.