# OData DateTime filter Edm.String error?

Tags: c#, datetime, uri, odata

I am writing an DateTime filter query in OData like this:

```
... + "$filter=SubmitTime lt datetime'2014-12-30T23:59:59.99Z'"
```

and met the following error:

[image]

I did follow the OData format guideline and other online references, and the string I wrote is aligned with the guideline.

So is this a problem caused by dll version? like stated in this post:
[WebAPI OData DateTime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978514/webapi-odata-datetime-error)

The Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll version I am using is:
**Runtime Version: v4.0.30319
Version: 6.3.0.0**

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems that you are using the OData library which implement OData V4.
In OData V4 spec, no DateTime primitive type exist, only have DateTimeOffset.

Could you try the URL:

```css
...?$filter=SubmitTime lt 2014-12-30T23:59:59.99Z
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! I didn't find such info inside the OData V4 spec (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html), where did you source this? Thanks!

Comment: I have annother question, besides datetime string like 2014-12-30T23:59:59.99Z, is there any other format the OData query support in datetime comparison, for example, if I want to compare by total utc ticks, instead of the explicit datetime string, what should the query looks like?

Comment: @RainCast you can find related info here: (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398153) and also in ABNF (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt)

Comment: @RainCast About your another question, OData support lots of functions about DatatimeOffset, you can find in the former documents above. But I did not find how to return total utc ticks.....

Comment: my API return date like this one '2016-07-30T12:52:16.007'. So how could I cast it properly?