# Odata filter DateTimeOffset less that date

Tags: sql, odata

I am trying to retrieve all records before specific date as follow:

```
?$filter=CreatedDate lt '2020-06-04T14:27:12.38'
```

but i keep receiving this error

> "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThan'.",

I tried to cast date

```
    ?$filter=CreatedDate lt cast('2020-06-04T14:27:12.38', Edm.DateTimeOffset))
```

but still the same .

also tried

```
?$filter=CreatedDate lt datetime'2020-06-04T14:27:12.38'
```

and received

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'1995-09-01T00:00:00'' at '21' in 'CreatedDate gt datetime'1995-09-01T00:00:00''.

is there anyway to achieve that ?

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 12):

You have to query date without quotation marks.  An example from my application:

```
http://localhost/EDS4OData/EmployeeHoursVacationRequests?$filter=(Username eq 'jsmith' and DeleteInd eq false and DayOffType eq 2 and StartDate ge 2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z and StartDate le 2020-12-31T23:59:59.999Z)&$count=true
```

In my C# model for the controller:

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick googling lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080733/8564999) answer,
so try

`?$filter=CreatedDate lt datetime'2020-06-04T14:27:12.38'`

Comment: tried this as well and received . The query specified in the URI is not valid. Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'1995-09-01T00:00:00'' at '21' in 'CreatedDate lt datetime'1995-09-01T00:00:00''.

Comment: did you try the suggestion for odata v4 too? from the link I gave

Comment: Yes ,I tried to change date format as well but still the same , i am not sure if odata support le and ge for datetime

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working like this:

`?$filter=CreatedDate lt 2021-03-19T12:50:54.219Z`

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27775965/3264998

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .NET sdk to generate Storage Table query try using the **TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate** version

```
var timestampToFilter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, 
                    DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-06-15T04:32:07.000Z") );
var timestampToFilter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, 
                    DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-06-15T12:32:07.000Z"));
var timestampToFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(timestampToFilter1, TableOperators.And, timestampToFilter2);
```